# Loop queries sequilze in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have a loop where I am checking if records exist and if not insert it , the problem is my console shows code inside loop doesn't run line by line , it runs all selects first and then run all inserts
loop from excel

```
tablesdata.map(async function (table) {   
    check if record exist
          await product_meta
                .count({
                  where: [
                    {
                      title: fr_name,
                      language_id: 2,
                    },
                  ],
                })
                .then((count) => {
                  console.log(count);
                  if (count > 0) {
                    console.log(count);
                  } else {
                    insert record create_pr = products.create(product, {});product_id = create_pr.id;
                  }
                  
        )}
 )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more straightforward to use `async/await` - the `Array.map()` is returning an array of promises that can be resolved using `Promise.all()`.

```js
const promises = tablesdata.map(async function (table) {
  if (recordExists) {
    const count = await product_meta.count({
      where: {
        title: fr_name,
        language_id: 2,
      },
    });

    if (!count) {
      // this will create a new product, perhaps it is meant to be a product meta?
      const create_pr = await products.create(product, {});
      // return the created ID
      return create_pr.id;
    }
    
    console.log("there are already", count, "product metas");
    return null;
  }
});

// this will resolve an array of newly created IDs,
const allResults = await Promise.all(promises);
// filter out the null entries
const productIds = allResults.filter((result) => result);
```